# Convert Objective block in swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

convert objective block in swift 3.

.h file

```
 @property (nonatomic, copy) void (^clickHandler)(NSString* identifier, CAShapeLayer* layer);
```

.m file

```
[_svgMapview setClickHandler:^(NSString* identifier, CAShapeLayer* layer) {
    NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale systemLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:identifier];
    NSLog(@"identifier = %@ & country:%@",identifier,countryName);
    layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    layer.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;     
}];
```

and when i am convert online , its look like this...

```
svgMapview.clickHandler = {(_ identifier: String, _ layer: CAShapeLayer) -> Void in
    var countryName: String? = NSLocale.system.displayName(forKey: NSLocaleCountryCode, value: identifier)
    print("identifier = \(identifier) & country:\(countryName)")
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
}
```

but, it's not working in project.

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working".  What part isn't working?  Does the clickHandler even get entered?

Answer (score 4):

I see one typo that could be fixed:

```
svgMapview.clickHandler = {(_ identifier: String?, _ layer: CAShapeLayer?) -> Void in

    guard let actualLayer = layer, let actualIdentifier = identifier
    {
         print("layer or identifier is nil for some unknown reason")
         return
    }

    // countryName is an optional and it should be immutable, too...
    if let countryName = NSLocale.system.displayName(forKey: NSLocaleCountryCode, value: identifier)
    {
         print("identifier = \(actualIdentifier) & country:\(countryName)")
         actualLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
         actualLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    } else {
         print("couldn't get NSLocale country code")
    }
}
```

If it still isn't working, you should try to check to see if that handler is being run on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: @Mahipalsinh you should mark it as answered if it solved your question

Comment: @Michael Dautermann it gives me error : cannot assign value of type '(string,CAshapelayer)-> voi' to type'((String?,CAShapeLayer?)->void!)'

Comment: ohhh, the declaration parameters are optionals.  I've adjusted my code for you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

there is a website where you can easily convert objective -c code to swift :-

https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main